# BeautifulSoup: can I prettify wihout adding extra tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = "<div><span>I am Spantacus</div></span>"
pretty = bs(html).prettify()
print("after:\n", pretty)
```

#### What I want:

A nicely indented and newline-d representation of the html, **without anything added** i.e.

```
<div>
  <span>
    I am Spantacus
  </span>
</div>
```

#### What I get instead:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <span>
    I am Spantacus
   </span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

From stepping into `prettify()`, it seems the `html`, `body` tags get added by the soup's `__init__`, not by prettify.  Is there some keyword or option to disable this addition?

Comment: could you try `bs(html).div.prettify()`

Comment: Ah, yes, now that works.  The only problem is that another time I may start out with something else than a div, so that's still only partway there.

Comment: No change to `.div` not .`.d`, it is the tag you want to print out

Comment: or I may input `<div>mydiv1</div><div>mydiv2</div>`

Comment: `for c in soup.html.body.contents: print(c.prettify())` this might be what you want

Comment: I'll accept it if you write it up, txs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to traverse to body and print out:

```
for c in soup.html.body.contents: 
    print(c.prettify())
```

Modify it base on your needs

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<div><span>I am Spantacus</div></span>"
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
# you can also use lxml for parse

pretty = soup1.prettify()
print("after:\n", pretty)
```

for more information [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Comment: yes, that works as well.  bit easier too, because I had to expand the suggestion by Phung to handle cases where `head`, `body` or `html` tags were present to start with or got added by BeautifulSoup.  I'll have to play with both approaches some more, esp as I use it to normalize html that may still have Jinja/Django style templating elements and/or Vue custom tags.  I know that works with the regular parser - just with those annoying extra tags - have to see how the `html.parser` reacts.

Comment: yes, this is the way you can get your HTML content. also, check parser for bs4 it will help it out.thank you, accept the answer if it is more useful so, others can help it out.